# Gnuplot: Using "With Lines" in combination with "every"command

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I just have a little problem concerning gnuplot:

I have a huge data file, containing several blocks of data and i just want to plot the data contained in the first line of each block. Thus, i use the every command:

```
plot "../path/to/data.dat" u 1:2 every ::1::1
```

The Problem now is, that i want to use "with lines", but gnuplot doesn't join the plotted data with lines.

There are two solutions I can think of:
The first would be setting the terminal type to "table", and then plotting this new table data file.
The second would be using awk within the plot command, such that I extract via awk the first line of data of each block in the original data file.

But I'm quite sure, there have to be much easier solutions?

Thanks in advance,
Jürgen

Comment: No, there is no easier solution. Points in different data blocks are never connected by lines (just see `plot 'test.dat' w l` using the data from @slitvinov). It is possible to hack this with the `vector` plotting style, but thats definitely not easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think awk solution is very simple already

```
plot "<awk -v p=1 'n==p; NF{n++} !NF{n=0}' test.dat" w l, \
     "test.dat" every ::1::1
```

With *test.dat*:

```
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8
9

10
11
12
13
14

15
16
17
18
19

20
21
22
23
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **gnuplot-only** solution, just for retro-v4.x-fun, but also for gnuplot v5.x without using external tools.

**Data:** `SO19792919.dat"`

```
 1   1.1
 2   2.1
 3   3.1
 4   4.1

 5   2.2
 6   3.2

 7   6.2
 8   7.2
 9   8.3
10   9.3

11   8.3
12   9.3
```

The shortest *gnuplot V4.x only* solution is probably to write the data using `every ::1::1` into a new file which looks like follows. Mind the "strange" datalines with `u` at the end.

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 7 points
# Curve title: "FILE u 1:2 every ::0::0"
# x y type
 1  1.1  i
 2  2.1  u
 5  2.2  i
 4  4.1  u
 7  6.2  i
 5  2.2  u
 11  8.3  i
```

and then plot this file with `every 2`.

```
FILE   = "SO19792919.dat"
FILEv4 = FILE."v4"
set table FILEv4
    plot FILE u 1:2 every ::0::0
unset table
plot FILEv4 every 2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" lw 2 ti "v4"
```

Gnuplot 5.x will not write datalines with `u` at the end, but will write empty lines which again wouldn't allow to plot connected lines. But gnuplot 5.x has the option `with table` which avoids these empty lines.

The following script works for gnuplot 4.x and 5.x, but with different outputs.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### connect data from different blocks
reset

FILE   = "SO19792919.dat"

FILEv4 = FILE."v4"
set table FILEv4
    plot FILE u 1:2 every ::0::0
unset table

set key top left
set title sprintf("created with gnuplot %g.%s",GPVAL_VERSION,GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL)

plot FILE u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb "grey" ti "data", \
     FILEv4 every 2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" lw 2 ti "v4"

if (GPVAL_VERSION<5)  exit   # following lines require gnuplot 5.x
pause -1

FILEv5 = FILE."v5"
set table FILEv5
    plot FILE u 1:2 every ::0::0 w table
unset table

plot FILE u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "grey" ti "data", \
     FILEv5 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-green" lw 2 ti "v5"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

With gnuplot 4.6.0 (only one graph generated)

[image]

With gnuplot 5.4.5 (two graphs generated)

[image]

[image]