# Gnuplot 2D plotting from 3D data input

Tags: 3d, plot, 2d, gnuplot

I have some data, which I would like to plot in 3d and 2d Graphs. I do have a data file which has the following shape:

```
1 1 2
2 1 4
3 1 6
4 1 8

1 2 1
2 2 2
3 2 3
4 2 4

1 3 4
2 3 3
3 3 2
4 3 1

1 4 8
2 4 6
3 4 4
4 4 2
```

In this case the first column is x, the second one is y and the third one is the value.
Actually I am using a file, which has 100 individual matrices, but I think that this example should be a little bit handier. :)

I made a 3d plot by using:
splot "data.txt" using 1:2:3 with lines

In addition I would now like to make 2D plots in both directions. So something like

```
plot "data.txt" using 1:3
```

using only the first matrix

and

```
plot "data.txt" using only the first line of 2:3 in every matrix
```

I found help at [1](http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html#7.6) in the section "How do I plot a part of data in a file?"

For the first case

```
plot "data.txt" every :::1:1 using 1:3 with lines
```

does seem to do the job

But for the second case I am not sure, how to manage the syntax the right way

```
plot "data.txt" every ::1   using 1:3 with lines
```

would not do what I expected. The plot is actually either empty or contains only one single data file.

Comment: I think your first example is wrong, it should be `plot "data.txt" every :::0::0 using 1:3 with lines`, note the zeros (which in gnuplot is the first element rather than 1) and the extra colon ":" in between zeros. This means "start plotting block zero and end with block zero".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `help every` gives you guidelines on how to do this. I agree however that the `every` option is a bit awkward to use. This should do it:

```
plot "data.txt" every ::0::0   using 1:3 with lines
```

It means "plot elements zero to zero of each block". Element zero is the first element in gnuplot.

To be able to connect the points by lines, you need to use an external tool, such as `awk`:

```
plot "<awk -v p=0 'n==p; NF{n++} !NF{n=0}' data.txt" u 1:3 w l
```

where `p=0` has the same effect as `every ::0::0`. This solution was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792919/gnuplot-using-with-lines-in-combination-with-everycommand).

Comment: plot "data.txt" every :::0::0 using 1:3 does to indeed the job, unfortunately it does not connect the individual points. I found another discussion about that at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792919/gnuplot-using-with-lines-in-combination-with-everycommand). Unfortunately I could not get the example given get to run with my example... Do you have any advice for that?

Comment: You put an extra colon at the beginning in your comment above. Regarding connecting points with lines, there seems to be no fully gnuplot solution, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792919/gnuplot-using-with-lines-in-combination-with-everycommand). Basically use `plot "<awk -v p=0 'n==p; NF{n++} !NF{n=0}' data.txt" u 1:3 w l`, where `p=0` has the same effect as `every ::0::0`.